# My heading tags aren't loading the way I want them to in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

My goal is to load a message wrapped inside (working) heading tags of different sizes a la

```
<h1>message 1</h1>
<h2>message 2</h2>
<h3>message 3</h3>
```

based on a random integer I generate in my code and using mustaches {{ }} to load the message from the Computed Property into the browser. But my attempts to load different headings into the browser have failed.

Instead of the heading tag loading up as I expect in big font, it just sits there as if it was typed as regular text.

I receive no error messages about it.

I've tried removing the `<p></p>` tags around the mustaches in case that was disrupting the `<h1>` tags within. That didn't work.

I've tried adding separate mustaches to load just the heading tags around the message I want to turn into a heading. That didn't work.

So here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
            <input type="text" id="input" v-model="someNumber"></input>
            <p> the value is: {{ someNumber }}</p>
            <button @click="randomNum">random a new number</button>
            <p>Result: {{ sleepyTime }} </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.3/dist/vue.js"></script> 
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#root",

            data: {
                goToBed: false,
                someNumber: 0
            },
            methods: {
                randomNum() {
                    this.someNumber = Math.random() * 10
                }
            },
            computed: {
                sleepyTime: function () {
                    if (this.someNumber < 5) {
                        return "<h1>It's okay to go back to bed.</h1>"
                    } else if (5 < this.someNumber && this.someNumber < 7) {
                        return "<h3>One more hours plus a cup of coffee</h3>"
                    } else if (7 < this.someNumber && this.someNumber < 9) {
                        return "<h2>2 more hours and 2 cups of coffee.</h2>"
                    } else if (this.someNumber > 9) {
                        return "<h1>Drill 3 cups of coffee. And just stay up.</h1>"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I want is: For example, "

## It's okay to go back to bed.

" loading as it does on the page here in big lettering.

Instead I get the text loading like:

> `<h1>It's okay to go back to bed.</h1>`

with the h1 tags displayed in the browser as text.

What to do?

p.s. I am about to leave for work so I'll be back to check on this thread at about 11:40 PM Pacific time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value output using `{{ ... }}` we be escaped. There is no way to disable this.

To output HTML you can use `v-html`. However, that is not equivalent to `{{ ... }}` as `v-html` needs to be hung off an element and cannot be used to create partial content.

So you can write this:

```html
<p v-html="'Result: ' + sleepyTime"></p>
```

The other option, and usually the preferred option, is to keep the markup in the template. That would look something like this:

```html
<p>Result:
  <h1 v-if="someNumber < 5">It's okay to go back to bed.</h1>
  <h3 v-else-if="someNumber < 7">One more hours plus a cup of coffee</h3>
  <h2 v-else-if="someNumber < 9">2 more hours and 2 cups of coffee.</h2>
  <h1 v-else>Drill 3 cups of coffee. And just stay up.</h1>
</p>
```

You could also do it something like this:

```html
<p>Result:
  <component :is="headingSize">{{ content }}</component>
</p>
```

Here `headingSize` and `content` would be computed properties that set the tag name and content respectively. You could implement them using a single property that returns an object, e.g.:

```js
computed: {
  heading () {
    if (this.someNumber < 5) {
      return { tag: 'h1', content: "It's okay to go back to bed." }
    }

    // etc.
  }
}
```

with:

```html
<p>Result:
  <component :is="heading.tag">{{ heading.content }}</component>
</p>
```